# how to get the name of an app in android using app_uid

Tags: android, android-studio, traffic, android-package-managers

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a tutorial or point me in the right direction on how to obtain the name of an application e.g "youtube", "twitter" etc using the app_uid. I am building an app that tracks bandwidth/wifi usage of apps on an android device.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String AppforUID context.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(UID);
```

What you're looking for should be achievable from the [Android Package Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: thanks let me play around with package manager and see what I can get